# In Blazor from child component call render on parent so parent contains child

Tags: blazor

Is there any way in Blazor to get a reference to what it's being rendered? Here is the idea. Having a component B (child) inherits A (parent), can I have the result of BuildRenderTree from B so I can use as ChildContent on A?

**Background**
I have a routable component Z which looks like the following

```cs
@page "\foo"

<B />
```

The expected result is, assuming both components render a `div`. Being `B` the inner `div` and `A` the outer.

```cs
<div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Some may recommend to do this manually, but the idea is the contrary

Comment: `<A> <B /> </A>` is not a result, it is an intermediate. And what do you mean with 'inherits' here?  The question makes no sense to me.

Comment: Layout components wrap the routed component. Inheritance will override the base types `BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)` by the existance of the .razor file. If you need the equvilent of the dynamic component expected in .net6 in .net5 I can show you how.

Comment: This answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64371526/6152891

Comment: @HenkHolterman inherits meaning hasn't changed. B: A for POCO, or in Blazor adding to component B the `@inherit` directive. True `<A><B/></A>` is not a result. The idea was to show the tree I expect, but for clarity say both components render a simple `div`. The end result should be `<div><div></div></div>`. Inner being B outer being A.

Comment: @BrianParker Layout is actually out of the picture here. What do you have on equivalent dynamic component?

Comment: What you're asking doesn't really make sense. `BuildRenderTree` returns a void, so technically you can't get the result because it doesn't have one.  `BuildRenderTree` is passed to the `Renderer` Queue as a Delegate and run by the Renderer as it services the queue BuildRenderTree.  When called the `RenderTreeBuilder` makes the necessary changes to the `RenderTree`.  It's only when the Renderer builds the DOM from the RenderTree that it gets tranlated into Html code.  In you question you talk about component A, but where is A in the very succinct code examples?

Comment: That fact that it makes no sense to you is irrelevant. Microsoft blazor team thought otherwise. Also @enet provided the closest/acceptable answer here. Most importantly, component `A` could be a 3rd party component, it is irrelevant, but read carefully and you'll see it is just `div`.

Comment: @yopex83  [polite] I think what several of us are trying to do is understand what you want to achieve, which we obviously aren't doing from your original question.  We are trying to be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the answer...its rather a comment (all my answers come in the form of comments)

Do you see this code:

```
@test(121)

@code {
    
    private RenderFragment<int> test => (value) => (__builder) =>
        {
        __builder.OpenComponent<TemplatedComponent>(0);
        __builder.AddAttribute(1, "Ref", value);
        __builder.AddAttribute(2, "IntChildContent", 
            (RenderFragment<int>)((context) => (__builder2) =>
            {
                __builder2.OpenElement(3, "p");
                __builder2.AddContent(4, context);
                __builder2.CloseElement();
            }
            ));
            __builder.CloseComponent();

        };

}
```

[Full answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65885509/6152891)

As you can see the result of the second RenderTreeBuilder (`__builder2`) is added as the value of the `IntChildContent` attribute for the first RenderTreeBuilder named `__builder`. In your case, you can change `__builder2` to create your Child component, and add it to the first builder as the ChildContent attribute, something like this:

```
__builder.AddAttribute(<sequence>, "ChildContent", <...>);
```

If it's not really what you're looking for, at least this code sample can serve as an inspiration how you can manipulate tree builders to build components in a sophisticated and elegant manner.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really truthfully the answer you want - but it is still interesting as an example of what you can do - and maybe it will make you think.

##### Component A

```html
@RFA(@<text></text>)
@code
{
    internal RenderFragment<RenderFragment> RFA = rfChild => @<div><h1>A</h1>@rfChild</div>;
}
```

Line 1: `@RFA(@<text></text>)` - if you use Component A in your app it will render it's own content only ( `<text></text>` is an empty fragment )

Line 4: declares RFA as a RenderFragment that accepts another RenderFragment as input. It will render its own content and the child content `rfChild` - in this case as child content of a div (I did reference at least part of your question!)

###### Output from using component A

```html
<div>
 <h1>A</h1>
</div>
```

##### Component B

```html
@inherits A
@RFA(@<div><h1>B</h1></div>)
```

Line 1 : inherits from A (oh, that's a second part of your question addressed)

Line 2 : Add the inherited RenderFragment (`RFA`) to this component's output, and pass in the Component B specific markup to be rendered inside A's markup.

###### Output from using component B

```html
<div>
 <h1>A</h1>
 <div>
  <h1>B</h1>
 </div>
</div>
```

Try it out : [BlazorRepl](https://blazorrepl.com/repl/QPkKbvEO50TrxjgK34)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way in Blazor to get a reference to what it's being
> rendered?

You can use the @ref attribute to get a reference to Component that is 'being rendered':

```
<MyComponent @ref=@MyCompRef />

@code {
    MyComponent MyCompRef;
}
```

> Having a component B (child) inherits A (parent)

No, but if you want to put B in a layout then you can use the layout directive:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div>I am the LayoutA</div>
<div>The child will be rendered where Body appears below</div>

<div>
   @Body
</div>
```

and to use the layout:

```
@layout LayoutA

<div>I am component B and will appear inside LayoutA</div>
```

> can I have the result of BuildRenderTree from B so I can use as
> ChildContent on A?

You can use Templated Component:

**Component A:**

```
<div>Component A Header<div>

<div>
    @ChildContent
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

Then in Component Z, you can put component B inside A:

```
<ComponentA>
    <ComponentB />
</ComponentA>
```

Comment: Ref directive doesn't fit the purpose nor Layout. Templated = manually.